# When are nodes created in linux?

Tags: linux, usb, mount

I am working on Linux kernel 3.4.56, and I am trying to add a system upgrade feature in my system using an external USB device.

So in my implementation, there is a check that, if `/sys/block/sd*(a/b)`, a node is created to ensure that the device is connected.

If it is created, then the filesystem will be mounted on the device. After that, it calls the upgrade script.

I don't exactly know when this node is created. So in my script when I check for the node, it couldn't find it, so the filesystem could not mount.

Can anyone please tell me when exactly these nodes are created in the `/dev` directory, so that I will check for it after its created.

Comment: I got tha answer of this question, At the time of system boot up, udevd(if started, also needs message mailer running) listens to kernel events and udevd creates a node for device as it detects presence of device at port. It also creates a link to a dir under /Sys/block/sd* (a,b,...,h), which is port specific.

Comment: if you know the answer, feel free to post it *as the answer*. Self-answering is allowed, and encouraged here.